# API development with Javascript & Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I've had someone build me a script that kinda work like Google Analytics, collecting data from a customers website or e-commerce website.

The problem I'm having is getting the values of each param.

This is the part customers would add to their sites.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window._tracker = window._tracker || [];
    _tracker.push(['set','API','tracking']);
    _tracker.push(['set','ClientID','abc123']);
    _tracker.push(['set','cart_id',1]);

    _tracker.push(['send']);
</script>
```

The underlining JS is here -> http://laravel.io/bin/bErMx

So the question is how do I get the values of like the ClientID, cart_id etc within Laravel so I can then use that as needed.

I then have the following method:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json([
           'data' => json_decode($request->get('tracking')), //get('ClientID')
    ], 200);
}
```

On the following route `Route::get('getStats','ApiController@index');`

I just need to know how to get the values of each `set` object

Comment: you can try to see all your request by `$request->all()`. So you can see what the request send to your backend

Comment: There's nothing in the request, likes it's not been passed from the JS